# build multiple layer restful API in node.js express

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am using node.js express to build simple rest API, I had built a API like

```
app.get('/sites/:site/:building/:floor',function(req,res){
    var building = req.params.building, floor = req.params.floor, site = req.params.site;
    console.log('query site ',site,building, floor);
    .....
}
```

when client did the AJAX request in angular.js

```
$http.get('/sites/london')
         .success(function(data) {

        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        });
```

the server doesn't respond to this kind of URL, unless I changed the express API to

```
app.get('sites/:site',function(){})
app.get('sites/:site/:building',function(){})
app.get('sites/:site/:building/:floor',function(){})
```

But the way above is too tedious so I wonder if it is possible to build API in one sentence `app.get('sites/:site/:building/:floor',function(){})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794709/defining-multiple-express-js-routes-using-path-parameters) should help you out. But to answer your question, the below should work

```
app.get('sites/:site?/:building?/:floor?',function(){})
```